# Convert Image to Base64 Including its Border Image Style

Tags: javascript, css, base64, border-image

I'm developing an app that allows the user to crop an image and also choose a border for that image.
What i would like to know is, if its possible to convert an image with a border style to base64 via Javascript?

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/222/Canvas_createpattern.png';
var pat = canvasContext.createPattern(img,"repeat");
canvasContext.strokeStyle = pat;
canvasContext.lineWidth = 5;
canvasContext.strokeRect(-(this.rotatedOffset.x * exportZoom), -(this.rotatedOffset.y * exportZoom), canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

The above code just adds a black border to the canvas.

Now, what i would like to do is to add a image/pattern as a border to the canvas.

**UPDATE: Based on @K3N's answer, i created a new canvas with the cropped image and added a pattern border. Worked for my needs.**

Comment: Definitely possible. You could draw the border and image to a canvas (you might need to create the canvas context with the size of the border taken into account), and then export using a similar approach to Cropit.

Comment: thanks for the reply. my main issue is that a want o add a css border-image to the cropped image and export all to base64. i'm able to add a simple border to the canvas, but i would like to add more complex image patterns as borders. how would i accomplish that? i updated my question.

Comment: There is no point doing this in CSS. You would have to emulate CSS styles (since you can't save out bitmap directly off DOM elements or styles) and still transfer it to canvas (with all the included challenges) so it's simpler just to add the borders directly to canvas without going a big circle around using CSS.

Comment: @k3n thanks for the reply. How can i add a image pattern as a border to the canvas? Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this directly with the canvas. Since DOM+CSS can't easily be transferred as bitmap for drawing in canvas you can might as well just draw to canvas directly instead of simulating the CSS styles and end up doing the drawing on canvas anyways.

You can use pattern in canvas but it's important to wait for the image to load. Image loading is asynchronous and at the time calling `createPattern()` the image may not be loaded and decoded which will create an empty pattern. Simply use the load event to be sure:

```
var img = new Image(), pat;
img.onload = function() {                            // wait for image to load
  pat = canvasContext.createPattern(this, "repeat"); // image is ready (here "this")
  canvasContext.strokeStyle = pat;
  canvasContext.lineWidth = 5;
  canvasContext.strokeRect(-(this.rotatedOffset.x * exportZoom), -(this.rotatedOffset.y * exportZoom), canvas.width, canvas.height);    
  // next step (if any) from here ...
};
img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/222/Canvas_createpattern.png';
```

Of course this will apply to images that are drawn to the canvas before the border is applied. For this reason it is advisable to pre-load all images you need for the canvas so you can ensure the correct drawing order.

Comment: Thanks @K3N, its working now :)  What i noticed is that the images aren't proportional to the borders width. Is there a way to do this? In other words, make que pattern's image adjust to the border width? Example: http://imgur.com/sV35utX

Comment: @Ricky newer browsers support setTransform on the pattern object which allow you to f.ex. scale the pattern before applying it. You could try `var f = dstWidth / img.width; pat.setTransform(f,0,0,f,0,0);` (and for y if needed). If the browser doesn't support you'd have to make an offscreen canvas at desired pattern size, then draw image in scaled, then use that canvas as pattern source.

Comment: I'm tried to use the setTransform() function but i'm getting the following error: .setTransform is not a function (I'm testing it on Chrome). Either way, i've marked your answer as the correct one, since it solves my main issue :)

Comment: @Ricky yeah, it could be a little [early for it](https://devdocs.io/dom/canvaspattern/settransform) (Opera strangely enough supports it using the same Blink engine). But in that case just use the other method.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Croppie`, it's a jQuery plugin that provides a `base64` cropped image as a result.

https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

I don't have a non-jquery version right now, but Croppie is decent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this plugin but couldn't get it working properly with AngularJS, so i went with Cropit. Nonetheless, my issue isn't the image cropping plugin, but how to convert an image with a css border-image style to base64. Updated my question.

Comment: @ricky - sorry to hear that, I know that binding the file to croppie is a bit of hassle, however, I do know that there was a `ngcroppie` directive for `ng-1.4.x`

Comment: i tried that directive, but it seems to have some issues with version 1.6.x. I'm going to have a closer look on the module for future projects :)

Comment: thanks for letting me know - may have to upgrade to 1.6 in the future - so it's good to know in advance